# Requests r.text (and r.encoding, r.content) are not working

Tags: python, python-requests

I have installed the package and was trying to following along [this](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) tutorial. I already installed `requests` and didn't get any errors. However, whenever I call `r.text` (or anything similar like `r.content`), nothing happens. Pycharm highlights it in yellow and recommends replacing it with a function call. I'm not sure why it's not working!

Example :

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
r.text
```

Run and nothing happens but requests website says it should output:
`'[{"repository":{"open_issues":0,"url":"https://github.com/...`

Thank you for your time

Comment: You need to assign `r.text` to something. Or use `print(r.text)` to see what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you're following is using the Python REPL (i.e. run `python` from the command-line).

If you're running a script from an IDE, you need to use `print()` or otherwise open a Jupyter notebook to get non-printed expressions to be output